# Is there something better than dict.get(<thing>, dict.get(<other>))?

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python,

```
>>> x = {'spam': 'a lot'}
>>> x.get('eggs', x.get('spam'))
'a lot'
```

But something just seems awkward about the `.get()` combination.

Is there some better way to say, "This could be one of two keys, I don't care which, just give me the value"?

Comment: I'd recommend defaultdict, instead. This pattern has quirky side effects, and it's a pattern I've never thought to use, myself.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: How would `defaultdict` be used for this? What quirky side-effects does OP's version pose?

Comment: @JohnY This *feels* like a default pattern (though it might not be), hence default dict. The side effect is since it feels like that, changing ```x["spam"]``` changes the behavior of the get.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: Well, what OP is really trying to do is either (1) try 'eggs', and if that doesn't work, try 'spam', and if that doesn't work, get `None`; or (2) get either 'eggs' or 'spam', doesn't matter which, and if both fail, get `None`. What factory function would you use for the `defaultdict` to get either of these behaviors?

Comment: if you don't mind writing the value of `d['spam']` to `d['eggs']` in addition to returning it, you could do something like `d = defaultdict(partial(d.get, 'spam'))`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most "correct" solution I can come up with is also the ugliest. That sucks. My two criteria:

- Avoid the `0 or None` corner case
- Short-circuit if one key exists

Despite its ugliness, this is actually the fastest execution:

```
x['eggs'] if 'eggs' in x else x.get('spam')
```

`timeit` results:

```
>>> op       = lambda: x.get('eggs', x.get('spam'))
>>> aaron    = lambda: x.get('eggs') or x.get('spam')
>>> ndpu     = lambda: filter(None, map(x.get, ['eggs', 'spam']))[0]
>>> mhlester = lambda: x['eggs'] if 'eggs' in x else x.get('spam')
>>>
>>> timeit(op, number=100000)
0.04057041245972073
>>> timeit(aaron, number=100000)
0.04477326960257777
>>> timeit(ndpu, number=100000)
0.13210876799140614
>>> timeit(mhlester, number=100000)
0.03425499248118058
```

Comment: <3 Python ternary. Apart from it being 'different' than other languages I never understood why it gets so little respect.

Comment: Except your version is the only one which can raise an exception.

Comment: Edited. It takes 50% longer than before `get`, but is still the fastest

Comment: +1 for concision. But speed should not be the deciding factor unless it needs to be.

Comment: agreed. my favorite is still OP's, despite the higher overhead

Comment: I think your timings assume worst case scenario, might not do as well in best cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would tend to do this, because it's perhaps a bit more readable:

```
>>> x = {'spam': 'a lot'}
>>> results = x.get('eggs') or x.get('spam')
>>> results
'a lot'
```

Your code looks like it would actually be more efficient, but it has to evaluate both functions, so short-cutting with `or` actually works better.

This might not do what you intend, if x['eggs'] returns an empty value, be aware of the behavior (but you did say you didn't mind getting either value):

```
>>> results = 0 or 'a lot'
>>> results
'a lot'
>>> results = '' or 'a lot'
>>> results
'a lot'
```

The unintended corner-case might be something like this:

```
>>> results = '' or None
>>> print(results)
None
```

Comment: But what if the `x['eggs']` is `0`? I'd want `0`, not `None`

Comment: As for efficiency, yours is actually more efficient because it can short-circuit. Functions need to evaluate all arguments before calling, so both `get`s are guaranteed to be called in yours.

Comment: @mhlester: Or even worse, you could get `'a lot'`!

Comment: True, for x['eggs'] = 0 it might have unintended results, I'll make a note of it.

Comment: Like @mhlester said, it's actually faster, and it's a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a one-liner, I believe the already posted ternary covers it:

```
result = myDict['eggs'] if 'eggs' in myDict else myDict.get('spam')
```

If you're just looking for the readable answer, I think you just go for the `if` statement.

```
result = myDict.get('eggs', 'fail')
if result == 'fail':
    result = myDict.get('spam')
```

Is there something unfavorable about breaking it up like this?

Comment: No need for `myDict.get('eggs')` because if you're in that section of the code, `'eggs'` is already confirmed to be in `myDict`. This answer is like mhlester's, except that you also suggest a longer form, which is incorrect in the case where `myDict['eggs']` in fact *does* equal `'fail'`. Also, `is` is not the proper test for string equality. Two very long strings can be equal (using `==`) but not be identical (using `is`).

Comment: Oh aye, that's fair. I'm so used to 'my_value is not None' that I applied the same in reverse. Whoopsie. But hopefully it is understood that the 'fail' value would ideally be something that is never a value for 'eggs' -- one would not use an egg-esque value as a sentinel in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I like Stick's answer, but I would wrap it in a class if it's the kind of thing that you're going to do more than twice (following the "rule of three").
Also: speed should not be the first concern -- unless it is actually required. Go for simplicity and readability.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def get(self, first_key, second_key, default=None):
        if first_key in self:
            return self[first_key]
        elif second_key in self:
            return self[second_key]
        else:
            return default

x = MyDict({"spam":"a lot"})
print x.get("eggs","spam")
# "a lot"
```

Comment: I was going to dismiss this answer, but re-reading the OP's question, I noticed he didn't actually ask for the shortest or fastest solution, just a "better" one. And this is definitely better if it's going to be used repeatedly. You can even extend this to arbitrary numbers of keys to check by combining with map/filter or list comprehension (as in ndpu's answer).

Comment: I've been playing around with (a variant) this answer, and I really really like it. Depending on the job the OP is tasked with this might be slightly excessive, but the implementation is easy-peasy.

Answer (score -1):

With `map` and `filter`:

```
>>> x = {'spam': 'a lot'}
>>> filter(None, map(x.get, ('eggs', 'spam'))) # [0]
['a lot']
```

with list comprehension:

```
>>> [x.get(k) for k in ('eggs', 'spam') if k in x]
['a lot']
```

**can be useful when more than two keys need to be checked:**

```
>>> filter(None, map(x.get, ('eggs', 'foo', 'bar', 'spam')))
['a lot']
```

Comment: Huh? How does this help?

Comment: Why did you "comment out" the `[0]` from the first example and not include it at all in the second example?  Other than these issues, I actually do think this answer is useful, in case there are many possible keys to check.

Comment: For completeness, it's also worth noting that this can be done with a list comprehension instead of `map` and `filter`.

Comment: @JohnY empty list can be in result so i think it is better to not use `[0]` with this method for versatility... and `if` needed anyway

Comment: I see your point about the empty case; but without the index, you could get multiple results instead. Ultimately, I guess you do need to do more checking to really get the proper functionality.

Comment: @JohnY if you need only one value it doesnt matter, check question. If you need several - it is already work

Comment: I did check the question. If you read the OP's code, what it does is retrieve exactly ONE value. That value is `None` if neither of the keys is in the dictionary.